Torus equation in conformal geometric algebra
How would you define a torus using conformal geometric algebra?
Since CGA has circles as a primitive, It seems to me that we should be able to able to define a torus as a circle C rotated around a point with a rotor that is perpendicular to the circle C. So something like:
$T = RCR^{-1}$
?

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

A torus is not an element of the algebra. $T$ is just another circle (and your rotor application is incorrect; it should be $RCR^{-1}$). You could represent a torus as a pair $(C, B)$ of a circle (trivector) and an appropriate bivector generating the rotation you stated. I don't think this would be terribly useful.

Corrected the question according to your comment. If I let $\theta$ as a free parameter of $R$   ($R(\theta)$), wouldn't that fully define a torus as a multivector?
